# Bootstrap Row Exceeds Container-Fluid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I'm trying to make a bootstrap `navbar` with 4 `col-sm-3` in a `row` in a `container-fluid` parent item:

[image]

For some reason, there is this offset where the row exceeds the container width, as seen in the topleft of the image. Do any of you guys know how to correct this such that the website will still maintain the responsiveness? Here is my `HTML` and `Less` for reference:

```
<head>

    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE=edge">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Morocco</title>

    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/stylesheet.css">

    <script src = "https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/app.js"></script>

</head>


<body style = "background: #efefef">


    <!-- Navigation Bar -->


    <nav class = "navbar navbar-default">
        <div class = "container-fluid">


            <div class = "navbar-header">
                <button data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-collapse" 
                    class = "navbar-toggle">
                        <span style = 'background-color: white' class = 'icon-bar'></span>
                        <span style = 'background-color: white' class = 'icon-bar'></span>
                        <span style = 'background-color: white' class = 'icon-bar'></span>
                </button>
            </div>


            <div id = "nav-collapse" class = "collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href = "index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "itinerary.html">Itinerary</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "trip.html">Upcoming Trip</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "service.html">Community Service</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>


        </div>
    </nav>


    <div class = "container-fluid">

        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "block col-sm-3" style = "background: #2980b9">Filler</div>
            <div class = "block col-sm-3" style = "background: #298bba">Filler</div>
            <div class = "block col-sm-3" style = "background: #2996ba">Filler</div>
            <div class = "block col-sm-3" style = "background: #29a1ba">Filler</div>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>
```

```
@import "variables.less";

@font-face
{
    font-family: Montserrat;
    src: url("../fonts/Montserrat.woff2");
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: Avenir;
    src: url("../fonts/Avenir.woff");
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: Proxima;
    src: url("../fonts/Proxima.otf");
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: Euclid;
    src: url("../fonts/Euclid.otf");
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: Besom;
    src: url("../fonts/Besom.ttf");
}

html, body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}

.container-fluid, .collapse
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}

.navbar 
{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Euclid;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}

.block
{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Proxima;
    font-size: 12pt;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    color: white;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: This rule is the problem: `.container-fluid,.collapse { margin: 0px auto;  padding: 0px; }`. Remove the `container-fluid` class from it.

Comment: @vanburen How does that work if you don't mind me asking? That's pretty strange considering the fact that I used it in my other website and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS rule is causing the issue: specifically `container-fluid`

```
.container-fluid,
.collapse {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

This happens because you're removing the `container`s padding which will then cannot offset the negative margin that's applied to `.row`.

Bootstrap [Grid](http://.row%7Bmargin-right:-15px;margin-left:-15px%7D) CSS

```
.container-fluid {
  padding-right:15px;
  padding-left:15px;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto
}
.row {
  margin-right:-15px;
  margin-left:-15px
}
```

*You'll also see overflow on you're collapsed nav so you may want to remove the rule altogether, not just the container-fluid part.

**Update:** The `.collapse` rule you have is interfering with the `.navbar-collapse` rule by removing the padding from it.

```
.navbar-collapse {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  background: #efefef;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Euclid;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
}
.block {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Proxima;
  font-size: 12pt;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
        <span style='background-color: white' class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span style='background-color: white' class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span style='background-color: white' class='icon-bar'></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div id="nav-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="itinerary.html">Itinerary</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="trip.html">Upcoming Trip</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="service.html">Community Service</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="block col-sm-3" style="background: #2980b9">Filler</div>
    <div class="block col-sm-3" style="background: #298bba">Filler</div>
    <div class="block col-sm-3" style="background: #2996ba">Filler</div>
    <div class="block col-sm-3" style="background: #29a1ba">Filler</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any reason why when I collapse the navbar I get the same offset in the side of the navbar